# find directional derivative at point in direction of point Q

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

[image]

I tried taking the partial with respect to x and y to get {y/(2*root(xy) , x/(2*root(xy) } and plugged in 2 and 8 to get {1,1/4} and tried turning Q into a vector {5,4} and then i took the unit vector in that direction to get {5/root(41),4/root(41)} then i dotted those two vectors and got 6/root(41). I have no idea why the answer is 2/5. Can someone please tell me if I did the process right? If I made a simple computational error?

Answer (score 1):

Because there is a flaw in your solution the vector in whose direction, the directional derivative is to be determined, would be evaluated by finding the position vector from the first point (at which point the directional derivative is to be determined) to the last point (in whose direction the derivative is to be determined).
Thus the unit vector would be (3i-4j)/5

Answer (score 0):

$\nabla f(\mathbf x)\cdot \frac {\mathbf y}{\|\mathbf y\|}$

$\nabla f = $$(\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}, \frac {\partial f}{\partial y})\\
(\frac {y}{2\sqrt {xy}}, \frac {x}{2\sqrt {xy}})$

at $(2,8)$

$(1, \frac {1}{4})$

$(1,\frac 14)\cdot \frac {(5,4)}{\sqrt {41}}\\
\frac {6}{\sqrt {41}}$

I am getting the same answer as you have.